# treat a single character as a char *

Tags: c

I have a method that accepts char *, but I only need to give it one char (which is accessed through `options[i]`, where `options` is a char *). Is there a simple trick to do that?
I know I can use my substring, but that seems awfully unefficient. I think I can get a temporary variable to do the job, but I don't like that. Is that the only way or is there a simple trick?

EDIT: I was asked to post some code:
my method that requires char *:

```
void quit(int errorCode, char * errorMessage, char * additionalInformation);
```

where I use the options char *:

```
for(i = 0; i < optionCounter; i++)
{
    switch(options[i])
    {
    case 'c':

        break;
    case 'd':

        break;
    case 'e':

        break;
    case 'k':

        break;
    default:
        quit(1, "No such option.", substring(options, i, 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just pass &c? Should be OK if the method accesses only options[0].

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it expects a single char, and not a string with 1 char in it? They are very different things.

Comment: @hyde the method expects a char *, a string, but in this case I want to give it only one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a local variable that contains a null-terminated character array with your single character, and a null-terminator.

```
default:
    char additionalInformation[] = {options[i], 0};
    quit(1, "No such option.", additionalInformation);
    break;
}
```

Comment: So is there no other way, without a temporary variable?

Comment: You need two adjacent characters, one with `options[i]`, and the second with a null-terminator. If you don't have those two characters to hand, and you don't, then you need to construct it. What exactly is your objection to the code here?

Comment: No objection, I just wanted to know if there was a cleaner way. If not, than thanks :).

Comment: @shoham without a temporary variable: `quit(1, "No such option.", (char[2]){option[i], 0});`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq That is surely a temporary variable, just one without a name

Comment: @PascalCuoq That's what I meant. But it doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012. IntelliSense says "expected an expression" on the '{'.

Comment: @shoham You'd need a real C compiler to use that syntax. You are not using a real C compiler. Your compiler supports (rather poorly) a 25 year old version of the C language.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, well I'm required to use VS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
char options[] = {c, 0};
foo(options);
```

Comment: But I want to continue using options and not damage its contents.

Comment: @shoham please elaborate on that requirement with some code.